# using c++ libraries built with /MT /MD switch from c#

Tags: c#, c++, windows-runtime

I am currently working on a c++ application built with /MT switch and would like to port my application to C# Desktop App. I also plan to use WinRT APIs in the c# desktop app.
Using WinRT APIs in c++ requires the project to be compiled with /MD switch instead of /MT, and i was wondering what kind of problems would I encounter when porting the app to c#.
All the libraries linked in the c++ app are also compiled with the /MT switch.

From what i could find on the internet, its possible to use libraries compiled with either of the above two mentioned switch(using c++/CLI wrapper or P/Invoke).

Comment: You cannot use pinvoke or C++/CLI in a WinRT app so you are not going to have any problems, it just won't work.  A C++/CX wrapper is required, get started with the Visual C++ > Store Apps > Windows Apps > Windows Runtime Component project template.  Run WACK frequently, the odds that an arbitrary C++ library uses forbidden winapi functions is very high.  But it probably just won't link at all.

Comment: I am just planning to use WinRT APIs from a WPF app. Since, there are a lot of c++ libraries that I plan on using from the WPF app i was just wondering what all problems would I encounter with libraries built using the /MT and /MD switches and if using WinRT APIs from c# would conflict with the c++ libraries(it shouldn't though)